# What is the difference between "Do anybody" and "Does anybody"?

Tags: difference, word-difference

What is the difference between

> Does anybody know...?
>    and
>
> Do anybody know...?

Comment: As stated before: please add some of your research and assumtions. See here for examples of what a well-researched question could look like: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Does*** anybody know? is considered standard English, and it is the type of English taught in schools. This is the type of English used in most professional and academic settings. It would be marked "correct" on tests looking for standard language use.

***Do*** anybody know? is considered nonstandard. It might be part of the normal speech of a nonstandard dialect. It would be marked as "incorrect" on tests looking for standard usage. People who speak nonstandard English are often marked as uneducated.